# phaser.io multiple phaser.game instances

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, webgl, phaser-framework

I want to use multiple `new Phaser.Game` instances with Phaser.io but everything when I create a second Phaser.Game object I get the following error `WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: uniform2f: location not for current program`

This is the HTML code I user

```
<div id="player1Holder"></div>
<div id="player2Holder"></div>
```

This is the JavaScript code I user

```
new Phaser.Game(700, 850, Phaser.AUTO, 'player1Holder');
new Phaser.Game(700, 850, Phaser.AUTO, 'player2Holder');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't currently embed more than one Phaser game in a single page unless:

- The games use the Canvas Renderer only, OR
- Each game is in its own iframe.

This is because Phaser uses Pixi.js for rendering, and Pixi doesn't currently support multiple instances of its WebGL renderer.

Comment: Thank you  i changed to Phaser.CANVAS on both instances and now it works!